# Is facebook application an object?

Tags: facebook

Is facebook application an object?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{objectID}
```

In [like fql](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like)

```
Query this table to return the user IDs of users who like a given Facebook object (video, note, link, photo, or photo album).
```

Could be this query used for an application? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's an object and you can like or dislike it

Answer (score 1):

see this
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Comment: I have read 1000000 times. $me = $facebook ->api('/appId/likes/');
                            print_r($me); and empty array!